# Further improvements with Imagemagick for text recognition with Tesseract-OCR

Tags: imagemagick, tesseract, imagemagick-convert

Original PNG:

[[image: original][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjmTy.png)

With this:

`convert original.png -channel RGB -negate -white-threshold 70% -fuzz 10% -transparent white improved.png`

Improved PNG:

[image: improved]

The problem is that text cannot be extracted correctly with Tesseract-OCR, it only outputs part of the last two rows (no lat-long labels):

`tesseract improved.png improved`

`cat improved.txt`

```
14° 29.9808' S
76° 15.7617' W
```

How could the convert call be further improved to correctly extract the text? Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Imagemagick, you can try

```
convert original.png -colorspace gray -threshold 25% -morphology open diamond:1 result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Much better, thanks for it, but after using Tesseract: `Bearing:
Distance:
Dy =o) dary
aT elo ae

14° 29.9808’ S
76° 15.7617' W

 
`, would Tesseract be the problem?

Comment: I know little about tesseract. But there are arguments in it for various issues. You are likely having issues with the curve that passes through the text.  I do not know how to remove that.